# Comparing two lists for unique items in each

Tags: f#, list-comparison

I have two collections (they happen to be arrays, but it doesn't really matter, I think): `L` and `R`. They are both sorted and now I want to compare them. I want to end up with two collections: one for each input array containing the items which were not in the other.

I could just take the first item from `L` and then search `R` and, if there isn't a match, add it to my "unique" collection (`Lu`). But that's extremely inefficient, and I am expecting to have some very large collections to process in the near future.

I though about possibly "playing hopscotch":

- Step 1: Take two lists, `L` and `R`, and compare the head of each list ( `l :: L` and `r :: R`):

  - Branch 1: if `l` < `r`, then add `l` to `Lu` and recurse, passing in `L` and `r :: R`
  - Branch 2: if `l` > `r`, then add `r` to `Ru` and recurse, passing in `l :: L` and `R`
  - Branch 3: if `l` = `r`, then recurse, passing in `L` and `R`
- Step 2: return `Lu` and `Ru`

I can write this function, but before I put in the effort I was wondering if a function already exists which can do this for me. It seems like a not-to-uncommon scenario, and I'd always rather use an existing solution to rolling my own.

(Also, if there's a more recognizable name for this algorithm, I'd like to know what it's called.)

Answer (score 9):

*(I wrote the question above about 2 hours ago. Since then, I found the answer on my own. The following is what I discovered.)*

In set theory, the "list" of items in L but not in R is known as "the relative complement of R in L", also known as "set-theoretic difference of L and R"

(See Wikipedia's [Complement (set theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) article)

[image]

F#, being a mathematical language, has this concept baked right in to it's Core library. First, you need to build your collections as sets:

```fsharp
// example arrays:
let arr1 = [| 1; 2; 3 |]
let arr2 = [| 2; 3; 4 |]

// build the L and R sets
let L = set arr1
let R = set arr2
```

Now you can call the "difference" function and quickly get the relative complement for each array:

```fsharp
let Lu = Set.difference L R |> Set.toArray
let Ru = Set.difference R L |> Set.toArray
```

```
> val Lu : int [] = [|1|]
> val Ru : int [] = [|4|]
```

There's also a shorter syntax. The Set type has [overloaded the minus operator](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/set.fs#L636). [`Set.difference`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/set.fs#L867) just subtracts the second parameter from the first, so you can actually just use the following:

```fsharp
let Lu = L - R |> Set.toArray
let Ru = R - L |> Set.toArray
```

```
> val Lu : int [] = [|1|]
> val Ru : int [] = [|4|]
```

Comment: More concisely, you can do: `set [1; 2; 3] - set [2; 3; 4]`. The `set` function works for any sequence (list, array, etc).

Comment: Oh, and also instead of folding the array yourself you can use `[|1; 2; 3;|] |> Set.ofArray` - functions that work with seq and list exist too.

Comment: @Daniel - awesome. F# just gets cooler with the passage of each day.