# Lists except - filter a seq of string which not equal any item.A of another list

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I'm trying to create a filter function accept two list parameters and return all the items in the first seq after excluded these existing (equal to `A`) in the second list.

```
type R = { A: string; B: int; ...}
let filter (xxx: seq<string) (except: list<R>) =
    xxx
    |> Seq.filter (fun i ->
        // returns all the items in xxx which not equal to any except.A
```

Comment: This is a set operation. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389733/comparing-two-lists-for-unique-items-in-each).

Comment: @Daniel - maybe not - if the original list contains duplicates, using sets may lose those.

Comment: In that case, only the second list should be treated as a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one thing would be to do

```
let filter (xxx: seq<string>) (except: list<R>) =
    xxx
    |> Seq.filter (fun i -> except |> List.exists (fun t -> t.A = i) |> not)
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest code would be:

```
type R = { A: string; B: int; }
let filter where except =
    let except' = except |> List.map (fun x -> x.A) |> Set.ofList

    where
    |> Seq.filter (not << except'.Contains)
```

Notes:

- Since the computation only uses `R.A`, we retrieve these `R.A` values only once for performance reasons.
- Converting it to `Set` would eliminate duplicates as they only degrade performance and not affect the final result.
- Since the type of `except'` is inferred as `Set<string>`, we can use member method `except'.Contains` instead of `Set.contains`.

Answer (score 3):

Fluent LINQ implementation:

```
let filter (where: seq<string>) except =
    let contains = set (where.Except(List.map (fun x -> x.A) except)) in
        where.Where contains.Contains
```

Answer (score 2):

There is now `Seq.except`:

```
xs 
|> Seq.except ys
// All xs that are not in ys
```